# Azure Mobile Server SDK: When the IQueryable is evaluated?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, performance, azure, azure-mobile-services

I have a backend on MS Azure built on top of Azure Mobile App Service SDK (namespace Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server.Tables and so on).
It is running ASP.NET MVC over a SQL Server database, in C#.

I have scaffolded my Controllers and I have the method `GetAllTodoItems` that returns an `IQueryable<TodoItem>`.

When exactly is this IQueryable evaluated?

I have set up a performance load test and the average request takes 46 seconds to complete, while my visible code and the SQL query takes maximum 5ms!!

What am I missing?

EDIT ====================

Here is my `GetAllTodoItems` method, together with dependencies:

```
protected IQueryable<TModelDTO> GetAllEntities()
{
    IQueryable<TModel> allEntitiesQuery = Query();
    IQueryable<string> visibleObj = context.VisibleObjs(GetUserID(), AttType);

    IQueryable<TModel> finalQuery = from item in allEntitiesQuery
                                    join visib in visibleObj on item.Id equals visib
                                    select item;
    return finalQuery.Select(Selector).AsQueryable();
}

IQueryable<string> VisibleObjs(string userID, AttachmentType type)
{
    return (from ud in UserDesktops
            join a in Attachments on ud.DesktopId equals a.ParentDesktop
            where (ud.UserId == userID) && (a.AttachmentType == type))
            select a.Id);
}

protected Func<TModel, TModelDTO> Selector { get { return d => ToDTO(d); } }

protected override TModelDTO ToDTO(TModel input)
{
    return new TModelDTO(input);
}

public TModelDTO(TModel entity)
{
    // all basic properties copied:
    Content = entity.Content;
    Width = entity.Width;
    Color = entity.Color;
    HighResImageContent = entity.HighResImageContent;
    ImageContent = entity.ImageContent;
    MaskPath = entity.MaskPath;
    MinHeight = entity.MinHeight;
    IsComment = entity.IsComment;
    IsInkNote = entity.IsInkNote;
}
```

Comment: First make sure the problem is not in the query itself (I suspect some client evaluation there due to non translatable `ud.UserId.Equals(userID, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)` filter criteria) by pre evaluating it, e.g. `var result = finalQuery.AsEnumerable().Select(Selector).ToList(); return result.AsQueryable();` and measure the time to get the result. If that's the cause of the slowness, it doesn't matter *when* the `IQueryable` is evaluated, you'll need to optimize the LINQ query.

Comment: Thank you Ivan, this helps for sure but it is not the point of the question. I already tested the SQL and it looks fine; besides, this behavior happens with a number of other SQL queries, of different complexity. The point of the question is to gather knowledge and "own" the stack, so that I understand really what's going on under the sheets...

Comment: There are few ways to troubleshoot if the delay is actually due to your code or network. First check Time to first byte (TTFB) (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_to_first_byte) performance with the current code. Next step, change code in your controller method to return an empty/static value and then check TTFB. If both are almost same then there is a problem with the network connection. If not, you need to proceed with the code refactoring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case it could be executing in several locations.  Pull the `GetUserID` method out and put it in a variable above.

```
var userId = GetUserID();
IQueryable<string> visibleObj = context.VisibleObjs(userId, AttType);
```

That may solve your performance problem right there - perhaps it is executing that SQL separately, then joining in memory.

In addition, `context.VisibleObjs` - is `context` the same context used by Query()?  If it is a different context, this won't use SQL to join.  You should be getting the context in the Initialize method of the controller and storing it in a class variable there.

Also, what type is `AttachmentType`?  Is it an enum?  Perhaps needs cast to an int explicitly?  Need more info there.

> When exactly is this IQueryable evaluated?

The point at which we *want* the SQL to run is when it is iterated.  In the code above it actually should not run within this method if written correctly.  **When it is iterated**, all expressions before `finalQuery.Select(Selector)` should be translated into SQL.  The `Selector` method obviously can't be run on the database, so at that time it requires to run the SQL as the query unwinds itself.

*The query will unwind itself during serialization.*

What does this mean?  Well you've handed back to the API an IQueryable object made up of an [Expression Tree](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/expression-trees/).  The Table Service framework may add some filters or sorts as requested by the web client ([see supported query operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/query-operators-supported-for-the-table-service)).  After doing that the web api framework (which called into your controller) will enumerable the `IQueryable` triggering execution as it writes out JSON(?).

We need to know what SQL is actually running.  That's key to working with Linq to SQL / EF.

When faced with troubleshooting Linq to SQL I often put a logger on the context's database.  `context.Database.Log = Console.Write` is the quick solution I use.  With a TableController, you would want `context.Database.Log = a => this.Configuration.Services.GetTraceWriter().Info(a);` in the `Initialize` method of your controller - where the context is initialized.

Then simply take a look at the log.

**I mocked up tables, schema, etc into a TableController and ran this myself, then went through the output with the Logging hooked up, so lets take a look at what's happening**:

```
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : Request, Method=GET, Url=http://localhost:51543/tables/TodoItem?ZUMO-API-VERSION=2.0.0, Message='http://localhost:51543/tables/TodoItem?ZUMO-API-VERSION=2.0.0'
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : Message='TodoItem', Operation=DefaultHttpControllerSelector.SelectController
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : Message='maqsService.Controllers.TodoItemController', Operation=DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : Message='maqsService.Controllers.TodoItemController', Operation=HttpControllerDescriptor.CreateController
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : Message='Selected action 'GetAllTodoItems()'', Operation=ApiControllerActionSelector.SelectAction
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : Operation=HttpActionBinding.ExecuteBindingAsync
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : Operation=TableQueryFilter.OnActionExecutingAsync
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : Operation=EnableQueryAttribute.OnActionExecutingAsync
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : Operation=TableControllerConfigAttribute.OnActionExecutingAsync
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131799606929250512): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Numerics\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Numerics.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131799606929250512): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Data.OracleClient\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.OracleClient.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
```

Next is the line in the log indicating that it got back the IQueryable:

```
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : Message='Action returned 'System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[maqsService.DataObjects.TodoItem,maqsService.Controllers.TodoItemDTO]'', Operation=ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync
```

Note, no SQL has been executed.  It now identifies that it wants to serialize that in Json:

```
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : Message='Will use same 'JsonMediaTypeFormatter' formatter', Operation=JsonMediaTypeFormatter.GetPerRequestFormatterInstance
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : Message='Selected formatter='JsonMediaTypeFormatter', content-type='application/json; charset=utf-8'', Operation=DefaultContentNegotiator.Negotiate
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : Operation=ApiControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionAsync, Status=200 (OK)
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : Operation=TableControllerConfigAttribute.OnActionExecutedAsync, Status=200 (OK)
```

Now the JsonSerializer is going to serialize the IQueryable, and to do so it needs to enumerate it.

```
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : Message='Opened connection at 8/28/2018 4:11:48 PM -04:00
'
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131799606929250512): Loaded 'EntityFrameworkDynamicProxies-maqsService'. 
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : Message='SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent1].[Text] AS [Text], 
    [Extent1].[Complete] AS [Complete], 
    [Extent1].[AttachmentId] AS [AttachmentId], 
    [Extent1].[Version] AS [Version], 
    [Extent1].[CreatedAt] AS [CreatedAt], 
    [Extent1].[UpdatedAt] AS [UpdatedAt], 
    [Extent1].[Deleted] AS [Deleted]
    FROM  [dbo].[TodoItems] AS [Extent1]
    INNER JOIN  (SELECT [Extent2].[UserId] AS [UserId], [Extent3].[Id] AS [Id1], [Extent3].[AttachmentType] AS [AttachmentType]
        FROM  [dbo].[UserDesktops] AS [Extent2]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[Attachments] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent2].[DesktopId] = [Extent3].[ParentDesktop] ) AS [Join1] ON [Extent1].[Id] = [Join1].[Id1]
    WHERE (([Join1].[UserId] = @p__linq__0) OR (([Join1].[UserId] IS NULL) AND (@p__linq__0 IS NULL))) AND ([Join1].[AttachmentType] = @p__linq__1)'
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : Message='
'
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : Message='-- p__linq__0: 'dana' (Type = String, Size = 4000)
'
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : Message='-- p__linq__1: '1' (Type = Int32, IsNullable = false)
'
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : Message='-- Executing at 8/28/2018 4:11:48 PM -04:00
'
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : Message='-- Completed in 7 ms with result: SqlDataReader
'
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : Message='
'
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : Message='Closed connection at 8/28/2018 4:11:48 PM -04:00
'
```

SQL complete.

```
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : Operation=EnableQueryAttribute.OnActionExecutedAsync, Status=200 (OK)
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : Operation=TableQueryFilter.OnActionExecutedAsync, Status=200 (OK)
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : Operation=TodoItemController.ExecuteAsync, Status=200 (OK)
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : Response, Status=200 (OK), Method=GET, Url=http://localhost:51543/tables/TodoItem?ZUMO-API-VERSION=2.0.0, Message='Content-type='application/json; charset=utf-8', content-length=unknown'
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : Operation=JsonMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStreamAsync
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : Operation=TodoItemController.Dispose
```

I'm not sure what the performance problems are.  While my table has no data I see that it is properly rolling everything up into one SQL.  Something that could be different?  The type for AttachmentType.  I used an int.

**What else?**

If you want to **own the stack** and truly **understand** what's going on under the sheets, There is a series of OData framework filters put on these that are up the call stack also.

This is the stack during the call to the TModelDTO (TodoItemDTO in my example) constructor, which is called during iteration over the SQL result.  Note that the stack doesn't have our controller method in in.  We've long since handed back the `IQueryable`.  This is back in the framework code where it's actually using that IQueryable, which I'm intercepting because our Select method calls into the DTO to transform it.

```
maqsService.dll!maqsService.Controllers.TodoItemDTO.TodoItemDTO(maqsService.DataObjects.TodoItem entity) Line 89    C#
    maqsService.dll!maqsService.Controllers.TodoItemController.ToDTO(maqsService.DataObjects.TodoItem input) Line 55    C#
    maqsService.dll!maqsService.Controllers.TodoItemController.get_Selector.AnonymousMethod__6_0(maqsService.DataObjects.TodoItem d) Line 51    C#
>   System.Core.dll!System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator<maqsService.DataObjects.TodoItem, maqsService.Controllers.TodoItemDTO>.MoveNext()  Unknown
    System.Core.dll!System.Linq.Buffer<maqsService.Controllers.TodoItemDTO>.Buffer(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<maqsService.Controllers.TodoItemDTO> source)  Unknown
    System.Core.dll!System.Linq.OrderedEnumerable<maqsService.Controllers.TodoItemDTO>.GetEnumerator()  Unknown
    System.Core.dll!System.Linq.Enumerable.TakeIterator<maqsService.Controllers.TodoItemDTO>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<maqsService.Controllers.TodoItemDTO> source, int count) Unknown
    mscorlib.dll!System.Collections.Generic.List<maqsService.Controllers.TodoItemDTO>.List(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<maqsService.Controllers.TodoItemDTO> collection) Line 99  C#
```

It appears that here, OData evaluating the `$top` query parameter for a page number does actually then put the results into a list.

```
System.Web.Http.OData.dll!System.Web.Http.OData.Query.TruncatedCollection<maqsService.Controllers.TodoItemDTO>.TruncatedCollection(System.Linq.IQueryable<maqsService.Controllers.TodoItemDTO> source, int pageSize)    Unknown
        System.Web.Http.OData.dll!System.Web.Http.OData.Query.ODataQueryOptions.LimitResults<maqsService.Controllers.TodoItemDTO>(System.Linq.IQueryable<maqsService.Controllers.TodoItemDTO> queryable, int limit, out bool resultsLimited)    Unknown
```

I believe the native transition here is SQL related.  I can't find exactly whats up in the decompiled source though.

```
    [Native to Managed Transition]  
    [Managed to Native Transition]  
System.Web.Http.OData.dll!System.Web.Http.OData.Query.ODataQueryOptions.LimitResults(System.Linq.IQueryable queryable, int limit, out bool resultsLimited)  Unknown
        System.Web.Http.OData.dll!System.Web.Http.OData.Query.ODataQueryOptions.ApplyTo(System.Linq.IQueryable query, System.Web.Http.OData.Query.ODataQuerySettings querySettings) Unknown
        System.Web.Http.OData.dll!System.Web.Http.OData.EnableQueryAttribute.ApplyQuery(System.Linq.IQueryable queryable, System.Web.Http.OData.Query.ODataQueryOptions queryOptions)   Unknown
        System.Web.Http.OData.dll!System.Web.Http.OData.EnableQueryAttribute.ExecuteQuery(object response, System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)   Unknown
        System.Web.Http.OData.dll!System.Web.Http.OData.EnableQueryAttribute.OnActionExecuted(System.Web.Http.Filters.HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)  Unknown
```

**To dig even deeper**, how does the framework know what to do with the IQueryable anyhow?!  Well when it iterates it, the IQueryable uses its IQueryProvider to parse out the contained Expression (note this is not compiled code, this is a tree of method calls and operators which you added using your joins and where clauses).  It transforms that tree into SQL (in this case) as best it can.  When it hits something it can't translate it throws up an error or finds a way to work around.

Gaining a deep understanding of IQueryProvider is a fairly complex computer science task.  You could get started [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546158.aspx) with a walkthrough of creating a Query Provider.  Once upon a time I wrote a query provider to transform Linq expressions into Ektron CMS API calls, and you could take a look at that [here](https://github.com/thesoftwarejedi/TSJ.Ektron.Linq).  I wrote a pretty good summary with links to key areas.

**I hope that helped.  Not sure what else I could have gone deeper into, and thank you for teaching me something new today.**  I had no clue what this mobile table API is (still not clear on the point of it)

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for! To your questions, I see the same SQL as you have retrieved, a single SQL with few joins. And I use the same context for Query() and VisibleObjs(), so no problem there. I have witnessed the issue with a large amount of data (100's of millions records), and probably what is driving me wrong is the MiniProfiler attached to my code (and to my EF6) that continues to tell "sql exec = 3ms"! I guess at this point this is the problem, that the SQL exec time of MiniProfiler is wrong and instead I will try putting a proper logger on the context's DB.

Comment: @CristianoGhersi if you could mark the answer correct that’d be fantastic ;). The sql may in fact run in 3ms. But if you have millions of rows returning, that’s going to take time to serialize. Especially if the stack looks like mine and that TruncatedList class in the framework is loading it into a List. Lmk what else you find. I can always load up a million rows if I need to and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Linq is lazy, which means that it is executed actually when you try to access the enumeration like in a foreach loop or some extension methods like .ToList() or .ToArray(). When you define the linq query in your method, than it is simple a "preparation" what should be done, when accessing the result. The preparation of the query takes just a little moment in contrast of the execution. This is the reason why you see that your own code runs in a few milliseconds. It's only a preparation. Finally when you access the result, the query is executed actually, e.g. when asp.net serializes your data to build the response of a request.

In your case you try to build a case insensitive filter

```
where (ud.UserId.Equals(userID, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
```

in VisibleObjs() method. The Equals(userID, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) call seems to enforce EF to query/return all data from the table before processing the filter when executed. The evaluation of your filter is executed on the client side instead of using a case insensitive search on the sqlserver. One possible solution can be to mark your sqlserver column UserDesktops.UserId in the database with a collation "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" where CI means CaseInsensitive. After that you should replace your filter by

```
where (ud.UserId == userID)
```

or something similar without using any .Net methods to allow EF to translate your linq filter to a plain sql comparison. In this case the case insensitive filter is processed by sqlserver directly without requesting the full table from sqlserver and filtering on client side.

Comment: Thank you Steffen, this is definitely helping and I will change this specific query, but still I haven't received the answer I am expecting: WHEN the IQueryable is evaluated, in WHICH method of the ASP.NET stack? If possible, I would like to follow the full process of all the filters invoked, etc. and instrument them so that I see exactly where I lose time.

Answer (score -1):

For the action which returns `IQueryable` data in `ApiController`,  the Web API will do `ToList` operation and then serializes the list value, finally writes the serialized the list into the response body, and the response status code is 200 (OK).

Only when we execute the "ToList" method of `IQueryable`, the data in database is actually taken and the "Excute" method in "IQueryProvider" is executed. (parses the expression, and then executes to get the result).

As you said that it takes 46 seconds to complete, i guess that you do some time-consuming operation with `IQueryable`, for example: Taking IEnumerable first and then filter the data will cause performance problems.

You can provide us with more detailed code for further research.

Hope this was helpful.

Comment: Thanks Lee, I just added my code, so that you have a better idea of the operations done here. One note: I am using MiniProfiler, and the SQL exec time is 3ms...

Comment: Hopefully, WebAPI will just enumerate and serialize on the HTTP stream (as a TextWriter) all at the same time, so you will run the loop only once and don't use big strings. If you do a ToList (or ToArray) and then serialize to string, and then write the string to HTTP, you're doing two loops instead of one plus extra useless string work.

Comment: Definitely we want to use the ToList once, but the point of the question is: where in the Azure Mobile Service Server SDK this ToList is done?

Comment: @CristianoGhersi please use [return finalQuery.Select(Selector)] instead of [return finalQuery.AsEnumerable().Select(Selector).AsQueryable()]

Comment: Thank you Lee, I updated the code accordingly. Still, the point of the question is: "WHEN the IQueryable is evaluated, in WHICH method of the ASP.NET stack?". If possible, I would like to follow the full process of all the filters invoked, etc. and instrument them so that I see exactly where I lose time.

Comment: @CristianoGhersi "ToList" wouldn't be used by the controller.  I should hope the framework is using an iterator and streaming the serialized text output.

Comment: Thanks @TheSoftwareJedi for the comment, I agree, it would be nice. In any case, where do you think I can find the actual code that executes the query, either collecting the results via the ToList or streaming them in the output?

Comment: @CristianoGhersi See my super long winded answer. Note, you can always force execution if you want, for testing, to happen right there with a AsEnumerable() or ToList().

Comment: Thanks @TheSoftwareJedi, I just finished reading :) That is exactly what I was looking for!